# Can I make different tabs of (gnome) Terminal have different profiles?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome

I've seen that it's easy to have the terminal set up so it opens up my tabs as I wan't to have them, but is it possible to have a different profile attached to each of those tabs? I was happily creating a new profile for one tab when I noticed all the other tabs were inheriting the options :(.

I'm using Fedora 16 with gnome desktop.

UPDATE: I see that terminator would probably fullfill my needs in this respect. Would the right thing to do, be to delete this question (as I prematurely asked without considering this option)?

Comment: No, the right thing to do would be to answer it yourself(as if you were another user), then accept that as an answer by clicking on the outline of a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Terminator should allow a user to be able to modify all the things asked about here.